# Image uploading issue

Tags: media

I have uploaded the drupal website on one of my domain and it is working well, then now I need to migrate it to another domain. Every thing was migrated but when I try to upload images from admin panel it is not uploading correct images. Means, if I try to upload let say cat.jpg then sometimes it display another random image from my directory. Strange issue, unable to figure out why?

I am trying to upload the following image:

[image]

And when it is uploaded it is displaying a random image:

[image]

Comment: Have use any cycle of random image_file module use? Can you provie link where it is display?

Comment: no I did not use any module for image, I had just taken the image field in my content type

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you clear you cache and if not getting worked  I suggest install [image style flush module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagestyleflush) and flush all your image styles.

Easiest way to flush image styles in Drupal 7.

> Image style flush Overview
>
> This module will allow Drupal to flush all image styles at once or
>   flush each image style individually right from administrative
>   interface. Features
>
> ```
> Flush all image styles
> Flush each image style individually
> ```
>
> Known problems
>
> ```
> Private file image styles can't be flushed with this module.
> ```